# How to get data in correct order from executors pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

Here is the code:

```
oRdd = new_Rdd.sortBy(priceToInt)
oRdd.foreach(printFunc)
```

After this operation I have data set sorted almost correctly. I would like to have at the end dataset sorted overall. Above I get sorted data set but per executor.

Output (e.g):

```
'8000'
'8500'
'8500'
20/04/13 20:37:30 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 598, boot = 558, init = 22, finish = 18
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\shuffle.py:60: UserWarning: Please install psutil to have better support with spilling
'2600'
'4400'
'4700'
20/04/13 20:37:30 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 1131, boot = 1108, init = 3, finish = 20
20/04/13 20:37:31 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 10). 1807 bytes result sent to driver
20/04/13 20:37:31 INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 11). 1850 bytes result sent to driver
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\shuffle.py:60: UserWarning: Please install psutil to have better support with spilling
20/04/13 20:37:31 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 10) in 1713 ms on DESKTOP-NK51QUH (executor driver) (1/3)
20/04/13 20:37:31 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 11) in 1718 ms on DESKTOP-NK51QUH (executor driver) (2/3)
'13000'
'13400'
'13500'
```

I want:

```
'2600'
'4400'
'4700'

'8000'
'8500'
'8500'

'13000'
'13400'
'13500'
```

Comment: `oRdd.foreach(println)` will run in parallel on your rdd partitions, so the order of the output of your prints is unpredictable. If you want to make sure Spark is sorting your RDD, just do a `oRdd.collect().foreach(println)`. Let's hope you have enough memory on your driver process to bring the entire RDD. This is not something you usually would do.. it's just to satisfy order validation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems to be in order.

`oRdd.foreach(println)` will run in parallel within your executors and are individually printing each RDD element of its partition of the Sorted RDD.

Your Spark application appears to be running with 3 executors. You can see in the following diagram how each executor only hosts specific partition(s) of your RDD (resilient **distributed** dataset).

[image]

In these prints you've generated, each executor must print its portion of data in an ordered fashion. Don't try to stich all prints in the order they are logged and conclude that the RDD is not sorted.

If you want to ensure Spark is sorting your RDD the way you want it to, just do a `oRdd.collect().foreach(println)` which will collect the entire RDD to the Driver.

In your case it seems you have enough memory on your driver process to bring the entire RDD to the Spark Application Driver (see image). This is not something you usually would do with big datasets.. it's just to satisfy your order validation.

With a Big dataset, bringing the entire RDD to the Spark Application Driver can result in an Out of Memory of your Driver process:

[image]